# Google Calendar Python API sample: unable to find the server at accounts.google.com

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-api, google-calendar-api, ipv6

I have been trying to access the Google Calendar API using Python recently, so I downloaded the sample program, ran it through the command line, and got this error after accepting authentication in the browser:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 133, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "sample.py", line 102, in main
    credentials = run(FLOW, storage)
  File "C:\Python27\oauth2client\util.py", line 128, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\oauth2client\tools.py", line 197, in run
    credential = flow.step2_exchange(code, http=http)
  File "C:\Python27\oauth2client\util.py", line 128, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\oauth2client\client.py", line 1283, in step2_exchange
    headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python27\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1570, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, met
d, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "C:\Python27\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1317, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body,
aders)
  File "C:\Python27\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1258, in _conn_request
    raise ServerNotFoundError("Unable to find the server at %s" % conn.host)
httplib2.ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at accounts.google.com
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Sounds like a connectivity or DNS issue. What does "ping accounts.google.com" produce?

Comment: I got:

`Pinging accounts.l.google.com [2607:f8b0:4001:c05::54] with 32 bytes of data:
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.

Ping statistics for 2607:f8b0:4001:c05::54:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),`


So I guess there is a connectivity issue.

Comment: You need to disable 6to4, Teredo and ISATAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your computer believes it has an IPv6 connection to the Internet and is trying to connect to Google via that connection. Unfortunately it doesn't actually work. Try disabling IPv6 ([Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852), [Mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3802), [Linux](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-disable-the-ipv6-protocol.html)) on your computer and see if that helps.